# Dart async*, yield* and exception handling

Tags: dart, stream, future

If I have nested async* streams, exceptions do not appear to be catchable, which is counterintuitive.

An example:

```dart
void main() {
  getString().listen(print);
}

Stream<String> getString() async* {
  try {
    yield* asyncStarError();
    yield await asyncError();
  } catch (err) {
    yield 'Crash';
  }
}

Stream<String> asyncStarError() async* {
  throw Exception('A Stream error happened');
}

Future<String> asyncError() async {
  throw Exception('A Future error happened');
}
```

This outputs:

```
Uncaught Error: Exception: A Stream error happened
Crash
```

So the exception thrown by `asyncStarError` is not caught, while the Future is caught as expected. Can anyone explain why?

You can observe the behaviour in dartpad: https://dartpad.dartlang.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `yield*` forwards all events from the stream it yields, including errors.
So, `asyncStarError()` produces a stream with an error event, and `yield*` forwards that error to the stream returned by `getString`, and then the `getString.listen(print);` does not add a handler so the error becomes uncaught.
(I'm guessing you're running this in a browser since that uncaught error doesn't crash the program.)

After that, the `yield await asyncError()` never yield anything. The `await asyncError()` itself throws, before reaching the `yield`, and that error is then caught by the `catch` which yields `crash`.

If you want to catch the errors of a stream, you need to actually look at the events, not just use `yield*` to forward them all blindly, including error events.

For example:

```dart
    await for (var _ in asyncStarError()) {
      // Wohoo, event!
    }
```

would make the error from the `asyncStarError` stream an error at the loop. It would then be caught and you'd print "Crash".

TL;DR: The `yield*` operation forwards error events, it doesn't raise them locally.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. Didn't know that about `yield*`.

Answer (score 1):

Since yield * forwards them like @lrn said, you can catch them in main just fine. Or wherever you are consuming them.

```
void main() {
  getString().listen(print).onError((e) => print('error caught: $e'));
}

Stream<String> getString() async* {
  try {
    yield* asyncStarError();
    yield await asyncError();
  } catch (err) {
    yield 'Crash';
  }
}

Stream<String> asyncStarError() async* {
  throw Exception('A Stream error happened');
}

Future<String> asyncError() async {
  throw Exception('A Future error happened');
}
```

this prints:

```
error caught: Exception: A Stream error happened
Crash
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that async generator (async*) exceptions cannot be caught by surrounding it with try/catch.

Instead, you should use the callback [handleError](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/handleError.html) to achieve the behaviour you are looking for.

To go further, you may be interested in using [runZonedGuarded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/runZonedGuarded.html).